# Verificar a diferença entre duas data em meses

Tags: php

Galera preciso de montar um código em `php` onde eu informo 2 datas e ele me retorna a diferença em meses. Exemplo:

```
 $data1 = "2016-03-01";
 $data2 = "2016-06-10";

 Resultado 3 meses
```

Exemplo 2:

```
 $data1 = "2015-06-01";
 $data2 = "2016-06-10";

 Resultado 12 meses
```

Resolvido assim:
     $monthsAhead = $intervalo->m + ($intervalo->y * 12);

Comment: não e duplicada não, isso e uma situação bem diferente.

Comment: Mas dá pra você usar a mesma resposta da questão anterior, porque ambas calculam

Comment: @HugoBorges Isso aqui -> `$intervalo = $firstDate->diff($lastDate);`

Comment: Postei uma solução

Comment: eu tenez assim: $dateInterval = $data_inicio->diff($data_fim); echo $dateInterval->m; porem ele ignora o ano, ou seja se eu colocar '2016-06-01' e 2015-06-01' ele me retorna 0, sendo que o correto seria 12

Comment: @HugoBorges não coloque a resposta do problema na pergunta. Adicione sua própria resposta na seção de respostas ;)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$data1 = new DateTime( '2013-12-11' );
$data2 = new DateTime( '1994-04-17' );

$intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Comment: se eu colocar '2016-06-01' e 2015-06-01' ele me retorna 0, sendo que o correto seria 12

Comment: resolvi assim $monthsAhead = $intervalo->m + ($intervalo->y * 12);

Comment: @HugoBorges boa!!!