# Contar diferença de meses entre datas

Tags: php

Peguei esse exemplo aqui mesmo, ele funciona, porem não funciona da forma que eu esperava, eu preciso pegar a quantidade de meses entre as datas, mas o resultado não sai como esperado, no exemplo abaixo o resultado deveria ser 15, porem o resultado é apenas 3

```
   $mes1 = '2018-11-21';
   $mes2 = '2020-02-21';

   $data = new DateTime($mes1);
   $nova_data = $data->diff(new DateTime($mes2));
   $calculo = $nova_data->format('%m');

   $total_meses = $calculo;

   echo $total_meses;
```

> De 2018-11-21 para 2020-02-21, a diferença de meses é de 15, mas o php
>   diz que é 3

**resultado**: 3

Comment: 1 ano e 3 meses. Se você dar um `echo $nova_data->format('%y');` verá que o retorno é 1

Comment: Você sabe como posso obter essa conta? eu precisaria de um retorno direto, tipo: 15

Comment: `$calculo = $nova_data->m + ($nova_data->y * 12);`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134313/60376

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mes1 = '2018-11-21';
$mes2 = '2020-02-21';

echo (int)abs((strtotime($mes1) - strtotime($mes2))/(60*60*24*30));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi desta forma:

```
$mes1 = new DateTime('2018-11-21');
$mes2 = new DateTime('2020-02-21');
$diff = $mes1 -> diff($mes2);
echo (($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m')) . " Meses";
```